# JavaScript Progress Bar in Loop

Tags: javascript

I would like to show a progress bar while running the following code. I'm calling it a script.
I need a progress bar in a for loop in javascript.

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<script>
var i = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 500);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: [you are using a wrong HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Progress)

Comment: What is wrong with what you've shown us? You haven't actually asked a question yet.

Comment: To clarify: are you wanting to rewrite this to use a `for` loop instead of what you've already done?

Comment: Progressbar also depends on some CSS styles.

Comment: Sorry! for not clarifying my words. actually, I want the progress line continually move never end.

Comment: What do you mean by never end? What do you want to happen when it reaches the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you want progress bar infinite execute, see this below code

```js
var i = 0
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar")
let width = 1
var id = setInterval(frame, 50)

function frame() {
  if (width >= 100) {
    clearInterval(id)
    i = 0
    width = 0
    setInterval(frame, 50)
  } else {
    width++
    elem.style.width = width + "%"
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#myProgress {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20rem;
}

#myBar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
    <div id="myProgress">
      <div id="myBar"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to add `id = ` before your second `setInterval`

Comment: Nice answer to the OP's question, but I feel that a CSS animation would be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: He said need for loop into JavaScript